# Crystal Reports Formula Evaluation - Once per section?

Tags: crystal-reports

I've written a formula as follows

```
whileprintingrecords;

shared numbervar level1;

level1:=level1+1;

ToText(level1,0);
```

And placed it into a report as so:

```
Report Header a |   {formula} {Text:Introduction}
 Report Header b |   {formula} {Text: Scope} 
 Report Header c |   {formula} {Text: Overview} 
 Group Header a |   {formula} {Group Header text}
```

The print result is

```
1 Introduction
1 Scope
1 Overview
2 Group Header text
```

I would expect to see

```
1 Introduction 
2 Scope 
3 Overview 
4 Group Header text
```

It seems the formula is being evaluated once for the entire Report Header sections and the single result is being printed everyone the formula is placed.  Is there any way to force evaluation of the formula each time it appears in the report, and not rely on some cached value?

Of course, alternative implementation suggestions welcomed too.

Thanks in advance,

Shamrock

Comment: Added separate crystal and reports tags (as on the duplicate of this question) - you can have up to 5 (I think) different tags on a single question.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. You can get creative with Running Total formulae.
2. If you're not suppressing groups, you could also try `GroupNumber+3` as your formula, but that can get confusing when you factor in sorting, suppression, etc.
3. If there's only 3 Report Header subsections, then I'd recommend just hard-coding it in there.  Add 1 more line to your code:

   `whileprintingrecords;

   shared numbervar level1;

   if level1=0 then level1:=3;

   level1:=level1+1;

   totext(level1,0);`

   I recommend this one.

Comment: Actually, see my Edits.  I can't immediately think of a way to reevaluate a formula every time it is displayed, but in your example problem, this should be just as good.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but #3 just returns 4 4 4 instead of 1 1 1 when the formula is placed in the same section 3 times.  The general question is how to get a formula to print a different value each time it is placed in a report, even within a single section.

Comment: Your general question is difficult to answer because Crystal thinks in terms of records, not subsections.  Can you give us the bigger picture of what you're trying to do?  If you're willing to put in the time, maybe you could do something with shared variables and subreports.

Answer (score 0):

Since the report header section only happens once per report, don't include the formula in the header section - instead, hard-code (ie. include as text) the numbers 1, 2 and 3 for the three report header sub-sections. Include the formula in the Group Header only, modified to read as follows:

```
whileprintingrecords;

shared numbervar level1;

level1:=level1+1;

ToText(level1+3,0);
```

Like so:

```
Report Header a |   1 {Text:Introduction}
 Report Header b |   2 {Text: Scope} 
 Report Header c |   3 {Text: Overview} 
 Group Header a |   {formula} {Group Header text}
```